# Set combo box visible text to nothing after populating it via a binding source

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I populate my combo boxes with a binding source using a dictionary, however this results in the top of the list being visible as default.

I'd like to have the combo box display nothing after it has been populated, as events trigger when the user selects a dropdown option(SelectedIndexChanged). So with an option which may be the one they need they have to select it even though it appears to already be selected.

Dictionary creation:

```
        public Dictionary<int, string> Get_List_of_SchemesID()
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> comboSource = new Dictionary<int, string>();

            using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                cnn.Open();
                string query = "SELECT [idGMRScheme],[SchemeName] FROM [DBA_Admin].[dbo].[GMR_Schemes]";

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, cnn))
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        comboSource.Add((int)reader["idGMRScheme"], (string)reader["SchemeName"]);
                    }
            }
            return comboSource;
        }
```

Combo population:

```
    public void Populate_SchemesID_Combolists(Dictionary<int, string> comboSource)
    {
        cb_Schemes.DataSource = new BindingSource(comboSource, null);
        cb_Schemes.ValueMember = "Key";
        cb_Schemes.DisplayMember = "Value";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two different approaches.

**First**

Change this method to add a new item to your comboBox:

```
public void Populate_SchemesID_Combolists(Dictionary<int, string> comboSource)
{
    comboSource.Add(0, ""); //To be the first item displayed
    // or
    comboSource.Add(0, "Select the Scheme"); // To be default
    // maybe you'll need to order by the key asc.

    cb_Schemes.DataSource = new BindingSource(comboSource, null);
    cb_Schemes.ValueMember = "Key";
    cb_Schemes.DisplayMember = "Value";
}
```

**Second**

```
public void Populate_SchemesID_Combolists(Dictionary<int, string> comboSource)
{
    cb_Schemes.DataSource = new BindingSource(comboSource, null);
    cb_Schemes.ValueMember = "Key";
    cb_Schemes.DisplayMember = "Value";

    cb_Schemes.Text = ""; 
    //or 
    cb_Schemes.Text = "Select the Scheme"; 
}
```

**Note:** For the two methods you'll need to check if it's selected the correct item before doing anything with the comboBox selected item like:

```
if (cb_Schemes.SelectedItem.ToString() != "Select the Scheme" || cb_Schemes.SelectedItem.ToString() != "")
{
    //do anything
}
```

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: The first method results in the new item appearing as the last item, and the .text method I tried before asking the question, but appears to do nothing when using value/display member.

Comment: I added " comboSource.Add(-1, " ");" instead of 0, and that appears as the first option, then just check if the selectedValue is -1 to do resets and not trigger events.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the combo's SelectedIndex to -1:

cb_Schemes.SelectedIndex = -1;

Comment: This seems to do nothing, behind the seems it may be default set to index -1, but visually its the first item in the list that is showing.

Comment: Hmm... That's strange. I did test this scenario without setting the SelectedIndex and it did show the first item. After setting it to -1, the ComboBox don't display any value. Also debugging it showed that the SelectedIndex is changed from 0 to -1. Are you sure that the SelectedIndex isn't set back to 0 after you set it to -1?

Comment: if I set this to run from a button it will set the drop down to appear blank while maintaining the items. But my function which populates the combo runs on load and it seems to not work there, or be overwritten.

Comment: Probably some setting is resetting it. I have tested it in the Form's Load event and it works fine from there. So you must have a setting that resets it. Try setting it just before the form is shown.